# Correct way to use DI when creating new objects in Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

MVVM, using PRISM 6 and Unity.

Bootstrapper takes care of creating intial View, which is in turn AutoWired to the ViewModel (i.e. View Model is resolved and it's DI's are taken care of).

Now the View Model has a Collection of other View Models.

This Collection can be added to with User Input, say with a button push.

The View Models in the collection require access to a singleton that I have to manage the "Workspace" (paths for image folders etc). So I would also want the creation of those objects to have that "Workspace" singleton injected into it.

In the method that would create a new ViewModel, what's the correct way to utilize DI/IoC to create it?

The only way I see it (dangerous to say "only" I know, that's why I'm asking for help) is:

1. Inject the Unity Container into the View Model that contains the
   collection, then Resolve the new View Models as the button is hit.
   The new View Models would be setup with a dependency on the
   interface for the "Workspace" object.
2. Create a `new` View Model when the button is hit and pass the
   "Workspace" into the constructor (of course the Workspace would need to be DI'd into the parent View Model to be passed down).

I have read multiple places that getting into passing the Container down via DI so that one can use Resolve<> isn't "correct".

Is this where creating a generic Factory would help? This still forces me to pass the container down, now it's just in the form of a factory though...

```
public T factory<T>(IContainer _container)
{
    return _container.Resolve<T>();
}
```

Comment: What you have probably read is that client code that does an explicit Resolve() against a service container makes it hard to know what the dependencies of a class are before it is created to which I say "bollocks".  All one needs to do is perform a static code analysis.  Explicit resolving is known as a service pattern and predates MVVM DI, Microsoft even has one that is separate to WPF.  The only real problem I see with DI with nearly every single framework out there is the manual config that is required ahead of time.   Bring on a simple factory pattern I say and ditch DI.

Comment: Inject any dependencies that are needed to create the child view models into the parent view model and then create the child view models using the new operator inside the parent view model class. Then you don't have to pass around any reference to the container itself.

Comment: Just define a factory class, that gets all the necessary dependencies via IoC and has a function to return a new item.

Comment: @MickyD - I don't mind the config as this is a relatively small tools app.

Comment: @mm8 - Understood, I was trying to keep new out of my viewmodels, but I understand it's fine they have it because they need to know about the model anyway.

Comment: @Gui - You said similar to the answer and I like this solution the mode. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often when I read about DI, it is treated as the be all and end all. I more often than not use IoC heavily even in my small and simple projects, however, it is just pattern and has a place like everything else.

The Microsoft Press book [Adaptive Code via C#](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/adaptive-code-via-c-sharp-agile-coding-with-design-9780735683204) explains SOLID well, justifies its use, covers the various forms of DI and the cost/benefit of each technique. For me, it made a lot of sense of these issues, managing project growth, and dealing with external dependencies.

I would NOT pass the `UnityContainer` to anything outside of my bootstrapper, other than a system which abstracts and breaks apart the bootstrapping/modularity process. In addition to the points you have made about this, Unity is a third-party dependency to your application just like anything else, and I would be very selective of which (if any) I tie myself to.

For your example above, I would use a simple factory. You could abstract this as far as you like, but a good compromise would be relieving your primary ViewModel of the burden of having to create its own children.

When using DI, there is nothing wrong with instantiating things yourself where appropriate. The most appropriate place of course is a factory. I wouldn't create a generic factory, as you stated, this is basically just like passing around the IoC container. Define a typed factory instead:

```
public interface IWorkspaceItemViewModelFactory
{
    WorkspaceItemViewModel CreateWorkspaceItem();
}
```

The implementation of this might look something like this:

```
public class WorkspaceItemViewModelFactory
{
    private readonly IWorkspaceManager _workspaceManager;

    public WorkspaceItemViewModelFactory(IWorkspaceManager workspaceManager)
    {
        _workspaceManager = workspaceManager;
    }

    public WorkspaceItemViewModel CreateWorkspaceItem()
    {
        return new WorkspaceItemViewModel(_workspaceManager);
    }
}
```

This class is an information expert with the single responsibility of creating `WorkspaceItemViewModel` instances. It has the right the use the `new` keyword, and have knowledge of `WorkspaceItemViewModel` dependencies. You may wish to insulate the ViewModel with an interface, but the value might be very little in your use case. Ultimately, you are using IoC, DI, and Interface Segregation for a reason, and when they stop delivering value to your particular application their use becomes noise.

Your view model could make use of this something like:

```
public class ExampleViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ExampleViewModel(IWorkspaceItemViewModelFactory workspaceItemViewModelFactory)
    {
        AddItemCommand = new ActionCommand(() =>
        {
            var newItem = workspaceItemViewModelFactory.CreateWorkspaceItem();
            WorkspaceItems.Add(newItem);
        });
    }

    public ICommand AddItemCommand { get; }

    public ObservableCollection<WorkspaceItemViewModel> WorkspaceItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<WorkspaceItemViewModel>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Prior to reading it, I just used a generic factory like I said in the question in order to have the IoC take care of the dependencies the class being created required. But now I see how I could have the factory take care of the dependency and pass it along to the class that was created; I'll probably go back and fix this at some point. With so many different types (its a database tool of sorts with many types, I wanted to limit the amount of factories being created to to keep it simple, however, many of these objects share common dependencies & could use the same factory).

Comment: Wonderful answer!